Entity Framework Core builds all projects
I'm using EF Core 7 and I have a big solution with multiple projects. Is there a way to build only my data project when I use Entity Framework commands (update-database, etc)?
Because in my case it build all of the projects in the solution.
I've tried to execute with argument --StartupProject

EF Core Power Tools VS extension might make your life easier

Wow ef core power tools is nice.. its possible to show the migration errors on the console?

I don't know - you can ask on the github or maybe on here - the author actively posts on SO (@ErikEJ i think)
